# Visualforce : Actionfunction method is called before variable is initialised

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery

In my table (generated via `apex:repeat`) I have this button "Show Previous Versions".

The button's id is prefixed "AWSPID".

This is the button's markup.

```
<td>
<button id="AWSPID{!awsvar.cnt}"  type="button"  data-target="#aws-prev-versions" data-toggle="modal">Show All Versions</button>
</td>
```

When this button is clicked, the following jquery will be called and also a bootstrap model will be displayed.

The jquery calls an action function as shown below with an `apex:param` setting the controller variable `sprevParentId`.

```
function showprevaws() {

    $("button[id^='AWSPID']").click(function() {
        awssprev(this.id);
    });
}
```

That variable's definition is below.

```
public String sprevParentId{get;set;} //this is the variable which i am setting
```

The last step is the populating of a list as shown below from the controller method `getoldAWSDocs` (invoked by the actionfunction).

```
public void getoldAWSDocs() {

    Document__c d = new Document__c();
    String spid = awsdocLst[Integer.ValueOf(String.ValueOf(idel).remove('AWSPID'))].Id;

    String queryStr = 'Select '+CommonUsedClass.sObjectGetAllFields(d).trim()+' FROM Document__c Where Parent__c = :spid ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC';    


    try {
        prevAWSDocsList = Database.query(queryStr);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.debug('~~~ Exception '+e.getMessage());
    }
    System.debug('~~~ Prev Parent Id : '+ sprevParentId);
    System.debug('~~~ Prev AWS List '+ prevAWSDocsList);

}



public List<Document__c> awsdocLst{get;set;} //this is the collection which is the source for apex:repeat and from which i get the counter value.

public List<Document__c> prevAWSDocsList{get;set;} //this is the collection which will be populated
```

My issue is when the button is clicked the action method `getoldAWSDocs()` seem to be called before the actionfunction is able to set the controller variable `sprevParentId`.

I could be wrong ofc.

*Screenshot below shows the tabular list*
[image]

Screenshot below shows the UI just after clicking the "Show Previous Versions"
[image]

Screenshot which displays Null Pointer Exception on Array
[image]

Can someone tell me how can I proceed resolving this issue ?

UPDATE :

This is my actionfunction code

```
<apex:actionFunction id="awssprev" name="awssprev" action="{!getoldAWSDocs}" reRender="aws-filter-section" status="actionStatus">
    <apex:param name="inpval1" value="inpval1" assignTo="{!sprevParentId}" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Comment: Can you include the action function itself, including your `<apex:param>` tag? This sounds like a common Visualforce race condition but it's not completely clear from the code without that.

Comment: @DavidReed Thanks David. I have updated the thread with the actionfunction